# Naming of Lifecycle Functions

Tags: naming-conventions

Does anyone have suggests for life-cycle names.  Lifecyle functions are those that control the creation and termination of software engineering constructs.

Examples:

- new / delete
- init / finish
- create / destroy
- connect / disconnect
- constructor / destructor

Consider in the following scenario:

```
myObjectPtr = myObjectCreate();

myObjectDoSomething(myObjectPtr,1,2.34);
myObjectDoSomethingElse(myObjectPtr,"a string");

myObjectDestroy(myObjectPtr);
```

Comment: Different languages have different conventions (Obj-C's alloc/init are simply "new" in C#).  Could you clarify which language/context you are referring to?

Comment: Language for this project is C, but I don't think that this question is language specific.  Create/Destroy work nicely in this situation, however I have been told that Destroy may sound a bit "negative" to some.

Answer (score 1):

The ones you have listed sound good. In general I'd stick with a paradigm that's already in place to make your code easier to read and maintain. In particular, the language or framework you're developing in likely has one already - I'd go with that. When in Rome...